# Listing Table Name from Object_ID in Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I found this script that will analyze fragmentation for a database using the system function `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` and give me the objectID, IndexID, and % Fragmentation of a given database, but I'd like to know the table name and index name instead of the ID.

The script was found here: [Defragmenting Indexes in SQL Server 2005 & 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/defragmenting-indexes-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008/)

And the query itself is:

```
SELECT
object_id AS ObjectID,
index_id AS IndexID,
avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS PercentFragment,
fragment_count AS TotalFrags,
avg_fragment_size_in_pages AS PagesPerFrag,
page_count AS NumPages
FROM
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('Hemasphere_Train'),NULL, NULL, NULL ,'DETAILED')
WHERE
avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
ORDER BY
ObjectID, IndexID
```

Would it be possible to get the table name & index name instead of the ID? And if so, what should I select instead?

Answer (score 2):

For the table, use the [object_name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) function.

For the index, join to sys.indexes.

```
SELECT
ips.object_id AS ObjectID,
object_name(ips.object_id) as table_name,
ips.index_id AS IndexID,
i.name as index_name,
avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS PercentFragment,
fragment_count AS TotalFrags,
avg_fragment_size_in_pages AS PagesPerFrag,
page_count AS NumPages
FROM
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('Hemasphere_Train'),NULL, NULL, NULL ,'DETAILED') ips
    inner join sys.indexes i
        on ips.index_id = i.index_id
            and ips.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE
avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
ORDER BY
ObjectID, IndexID
```

Comment: When I do that, the table_name and Index_name are all returned as 'NULL'.

Comment: @MISNole Are you running this query from within the `Hemasphere_Train` database?

Comment: No, from master. When I try to run it from the `Hemasphere_Train` database, it throws the error: Incorrect syntax near 'Hemasphere_Train' on the line `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('Hemasphere_Train'),NULL, NULL, NULL ,'DETAILED')`